# __doPostBack on event works only once

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dopostback

I have a hidden asp control that has a server event to it (valuechanged). I call the javascript __doPostBack method and as a parameter I send the id of the hidden control which makes it raise the valuechanged event after the Page_Load. It works fine for the first time, but the other times it posts back without raising the event.
Is there anything I am missing here? Is it caching the postback?

EDIT:

The hidden field is in an updatepanel, so the __doPostBack doesn't refresh the whole page

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: A basic hidden asp tag with valuechanged event, and the javascript line is __doPostBack('hiddenid', ''); which is activated later

Comment: @Marlon Vidal, I added another piece of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well silly me.
It won't raise the valuechanged event if you call __doPostBack on a control that its value remained the same!
Oopsie...